# Bash - Insert string with newlines after the information, that looks like block of text

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a string (**$pastestring**) with newlines, that I declared like this

> pastestring=$'\n##### Branch FREEZE enable/disable:\n Freeze: enable '

I have a document (with path **$file**). The document is rather big, but my task is: when i find a text, that is simular to this.

```
######## Branch Owner #########
Owner: James Jones
Mail: James@gmail.com
###############################
```

*(so the amount of "#" symbols can be different, Owner and Mail parameters can be different too)*

I need to make a new line and paste information that I have inside of document, so it should look like

```
######## Branch Owner #########
Owner: James Jones
Mail: James@gmail.com
###############################

##### Branch FREEZE enable/disable
Freeze: enable
```

First of all, I don't really know, how to make a pattern that will help me to find a text, that looks like the text above (I don't know, how to pattern with newlines inside).

If I am trying to paste my test like this (in this case I look only at "###############################" symbols)

> sed -i "/###############################/a "${pastestring}"" $file

I get a lot of mistakes because of newlines and special symbols inside of string.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: expected \ after `a', `c' or `i'
```

Any help to fixing this appreciated!

**UPDATE**
@Inian
The content of the **$file** looks like this

```
######## Branch Owner #########
Owner: Jones Jane
Mail: Jones@gmail.com
###############################

##### Branch RELEASE enable/disable
Release: disable

##### Branch configuration enable/disable
Release: enable

##### Branch output enable/disable
Release: enable
```

I need to put my string in file after

```
######## Branch Owner #########
Owner: Jones Jane
Mail: Jones@gmail.com
###############################
```

It can be identified, by the way, that it looks

```
##### (some symbols #)
Owner: (some text)
Mail: (some text)
##### (some symbols #)
```

And I don't really know, how to make a pattern for it.

The result should be

```
######## Branch Owner #########
Owner: Jones Jane
Mail: Jones@gmail.com
###############################

##### Branch FREEZE enable/disable
Freeze: disable

##### Branch RELEASE enable/disable
Release: disable

##### Branch configuration enable/disable
Release: enable

##### Branch output enable/disable
Release: enable
```

**UPDATE**
@Inian, could you take a look again? I have just found out another problem here. Your scripts pastes the text twice. The content of file is

```
######## Branch Owner #########
Owner: Jones Jane
Mail: Jones@gmail.com
###############################

##### Branch RELEASE enable/disable
Release: disable

##### Branch configuration enable/disable
Release: enable

##### Branch output enable/disable
Release: enable

##### Branch Contributors #####
user1
user2
user3
user4
yooseftal
markout
(and other users)
###############################


#### Code Review enable/disable
CR: enable
```

So the script pastes text also after the **Branch Contributors** section

Comment: It is not generally advised in stack overflow, bring in new requirments (or) not showing the actual input fully in the first place. Please provide a snippet with all your cases, so that it can be tested once and be done with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using `Awk` for this, you can do it as below,

```
pastestring=$'\n##### Branch FREEZE enable/disable:\nFreeze: enable '
awk -v string="${pastestring}" '/Branch Owner/{print; flag=1; next}$0 ~ "^[#]*$" && flag && NF{print; print string; flag=0; next}1' file "$file"
```

which produces an output as below,

```
######## Branch Owner #########
Owner: James Jones
Mail: James@gmail.com
###############################

##### Branch FREEZE enable/disable:
Freeze: enable
```

The key to the solution is to identify the `regex` only for the line starting with `#` which can be done by

```
$0 ~ "^[#]*$"
```

which means if *line* contains *only* the `#` character, print that line and print the line required and the condition `&& NF` to ensure the regex doesn't match *blank* lines for performing the new line insertion. The `/Branch Owner/{flag=1; next}` is to ensure no other similar tags are matched for appending below.

The part `-v string="${pastestring}"` imports the variable in `bash` context to the context of `Awk` since them both being different.

In-case, you want to over-write the file with the new contents, create a temporary file from the output of `awk` and re-direct it back to the original file ( equivalent of your `sed` *in-place* editing)

```
awk -v string="${pastestring}" '/Branch Owner/{print; flag=1; next}$0 ~ "^[#]*$" && flag && NF{print; print string; flag=0; next}1' "$file" > temp && mv temp "$file"
```

Comment: @IlyaBogomolnyy: Could you try my update? `awk -v string="${pastestring}" '$0 ~ "^[#]*$" && NF{print; print string; next}1' "$file"`

Comment: That is just unbelievable! It works great! I'll need some time to figure out how it works, but it is really impressive! Thank you

Comment: @IlyaBogomolnyy: Appreciate your feedback! Thanks!

Comment: could you take a look one more time? One problem occured, the script pastes a string twice, but it needs to be pasted only once

Comment: @IlyaBogomolnyy: This is not generally advised in stack overflow, bring in new requirments (or) not showing the actual input fully in the first place. Please provide a snippet with all your cases, so that it can be tested once and be done with it

Comment: I am sorry. I just have a block that looks like sample, that is above. And I need to paste my string only after the block, that looks like it. **Branch contributer** block is different from **Branch Owner** block

Comment: it is good, but it somehow deletes the first string of file **######## Branch Owner #########** - this text

Answer (score 0):

A `Perl` solution that performs an inplace replacement and checks `Mail` pattern:

```
perl -0777  -i -pne 's/(Mail:[^\n]*\n#+\n)/\1\n##### Branch FREEZE enable\/disable\nFreeze: enable\n/g' your_file
```

---

```
$ cat your_file
######## Branch Owner #########
Owner: Jones Jane
Mail: Jones@gmail.com
###############################

##### Branch FREEZE enable/disable
Freeze: enable

##### Branch RELEASE enable/disable
Release: disable

##### Branch configuration enable/disable
Release: enable

##### Branch output enable/disable
Release: enable
```